# Uncharacteristic file-read operation using QTextStream in Linux 

Tags: file, qt, stream, seek, file-read

I am using linux platform (Ubuntu) and QT4.7.4 ,

first, I create a test file "test.txt" using vi , just write 100000 lines "1234567890" in it,

Then I compile &  run the codes below,  to my supervising ,it enter infinite loop ,

any ideas about it ? Thanks!

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);
    QString str;

    QFile file("./test.txt");
    if ( file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text) ) {

        QTextStream ts( &file );
        while(!ts.atEnd()) {
            str = ts.read(10240);
            qDebug()<<"s:"<<ts.status()<<":"<<ts.atEnd()<<":"<<str.count()<<":"<<ts.pos();

        }
    }
    return app.exec();
}
```

here is the qdebug output:

```
s: 0 : false : 10240 : 10240 
s: 0 : false : 10240 : 20480 
s: 0 : false : 10240 : 51200 
s: 0 : false : 10240 : 112640 
s: 0 : false : 10240 : 235520 
s: 0 : false : 10240 : 481280 
s: 0 : false : 10240 : 972800 
s: 0 : false : 10240 : -1 
s: 0 : false : 10240 : -1 
s: 0 : false : 10240 : -1 
s: 0 : false : 10240 : -1 
s: 0 : false : 10240 : -1 
s: 0 : false : 10240 : -1 
s: 0 : false : 10240 : -1 
....
```

here are some infos about test.txt

```
$du  -sh test.txt 
1.1M    test.txt

$wc -c test.txt 
1100011 test.txt

$du -S test.txt 
1076    test.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was [a bug in `QTextStream::pos`](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-9814), which prevented to use `pos()` with files bigger than 16KB (I think), it seems to have been [fixed](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/commit/17a4f332f0d416af842145f0ebc7f2ebe7f33527) somewhere between Qt 4.7 and 4.8.

But anyway, using `QTextStream::pos()` inside that loop is terribly impacting the reading speed, so, you should avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

Somehow your seek pointer lost track somewhere. This may be in internal call to seek function made by `pos()` function.

So try to seek your pointer manually in every iteration. I suggest reading small chunks of data in iteration.

Try this

```
       int pos=0;
       QTextStream ts( &file );
       while(!ts.atEnd()) {
           pos+=5120;
           {
               str = ts.read(5120);

               qDebug()<<"s:"<<ts.status()<<":"<<ts.atEnd()<<":"<<str.count()<<":"<<ts.pos();
               ts.seek(pos);//manually seeking to current position
           }

       }
```

This should work.

And you will see `s: 0 : true : (final-chunk-data-size) : (size-of-your-test.txt-file)` as final line in your qdebug output.

The problem is with `ts.pos();` in `line`  `qDebug()<<"s:"<<ts.status()<<":"<<ts.atEnd()<<":"<<str.count()<<":"<<ts.pos();`
Since QTextStream is buffered, the pos() function may have to seek the device to reconstruct a valid device position.[there is a chance that, if you use QFile and TextStream in conjunction, the text stream's internal position will be out of sync with the file's position, that way this seek function used inernally  by pos() function may go terribly wrong!!]

So if you use it without calling `ts.pos()` it will go alright. You don't have to manually `seek`. Otherwise, if you add ts.pos(), you should manually `seek`.

See the sequence of pos output, it always add (10240 + the previous position) to the previous position value in every pos() call. that means it jumps by an amount of previous position values in every pos() call as it is out-of-synch with file's position by an amount of previous pos. So if you call pos(), that out-of-synch is reflected in your texstream object.

Comment: test.txt is 752K ,I add about 70000 lines "1234567890", but the output still incorrect, is it a QTextStream bug?

Comment: Well I tested it in my sys with file having size 788kb. and qdebug was called 158 times since I read data as 5k chunk. And no indefinite execution. Did you try the way I mentioned ?

Comment: it works using the seek function, thanks! but still confusing why Qtextstream never report EOF in this case

Comment: according to alexisdm, it a bug in QTextStream::pos, Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be some problem with the file that you are trying to read. Check the file encoding of test.txt. If you see the size of data read, you will see anomalies with the text read, the reading moves from 20K to 50K to 100K.

The code is fine and working for me.

Comment: I create the test.txt using VI , here is my steps: input one line "1234567890" , "yy" , "100000 p" , wq

Comment: @camino The mechanism does not matter here. Try creating the same file with some other editor, or better still run the same program with some of the big files from /var/*.log

Comment: ,as mentioned in the post of alexisdm, it was a bug in QTextStream::pos function , I am using QT 4.7.4 linux platform.